# Trouble with 1st order axiomatization of periods, are there reasons to avoid 2-sorted logic?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am an undergrad working on my senior thesis. I am trying to come up with a first order axiomatization for the ring of period numbers. However, due to the nature of the ring I am trying to describe, I keep finding it necessary to quantify over a specific family of function symbols. Alternatively, I might be able to make it work by quantifying over the rationals as well as a subset of my broader structure.

My gut tells me that using a 2-sorted logic would make it more difficult to use the model theory tools I've learned to reason about these numbers, and it feels much messier. That being said, I am fairly new to the topic. My only real experience with model theory is half of Marker's text, and he does not go into much detail about many sorted logics, taking only two pages to briefly define them. It might be possible my desire to avoid 2-sorted logic is unfounded. I would appreciate any guidance on how to proceed,  or any suggested reading.

Comment: Note that it's still open whether the ring of periods is even a field (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20497/is-it-known-that-the-ring-of-periods-is-not-a-field)), so I don't think that coming up with a snappy axiomatization in the language of rings alone is possible with our current understanding.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks :) and yeah, I know, I wasn't thinking it would be easy to axiomatize, I am just  trying to get a feel for the first order properties of this ring, and what we can and cannot say about em.

Comment: I think you have chosen a challenging problem.Typically, using 2-sorted logic makes things nicer if it fits the problem in question: a single-sorted approach to vector space theory, say, requires you to mess around with predicates for "being a scalar" and "being a vector". In the case of periods, aren't you going to have to quantifier over rational functions and work with integrals? I think you are going to need higher-order logic to capture those notions.